# Can I return an Object of custom type using afterThrowing() method in spring?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a situation where I want to mock a web service call. The approach I am using is if the service is down, it throws an exception. I intent to use that exception using `ThrowAdvice AOP` in spring and want to suppress the exception and replace the response object with my dummy object. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Around advice to intercept the method. This advice will give you absolute control. In this advice you can catch the exception and return the require response

```
@Around("execution(abc.example.*Service.*(..))")
public ResultType execute(ProceedingJoinPoint p) {
    ResultType result = null;
    try {
        result = (ResultType) p.proceed();
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable t) {}
    // Create dummy result
    return result;
}
```

ResultType can be any type, but be sure not intercept service which are not returning same type or subtype

Comment: If I get it right, Using around Advice will make me change my business logic, like creating a dummy object and all. I dont want to touch the business logic. It should be like if exception is thrown then call is delegated to another method (aop method) and return value should be given by that method.

Comment: And that would not be changing the business logic? The answer is correct, just use the around advice and be happy with it. Don't speculate, try it!